# How to find if a given timestamp is within a cron-expression?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am using the [quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule some jobs in Java using cron expressions, and have come across the need to find you whether a **given timestamp** is within a specified cron expression. That is to say, would a scheduled job with this cron run at the given timestamp?

I am not confined to using quartz library to solve this problem, so any solution is welcome.

Comment: does anyone actually know the answer? recently I also got stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is

Date getFireTimeAfter(Date afterTime)

In the trigger interface.

You could check what the next firetime t-1 is when t is the time you want to Check. If the result equals t you know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Calendar.html) interface has just the method you need to check if a **timestamp** is "included" in the Calendar and thus the CronTrigger will fire with the given timestamp:

```
boolean includedisTimeIncluded(long timeStamp)
```

- You can take the *Calendar name* from the CronTrigger using the Inherited Trigger method:

  ```
  String calendarName = myTrigger.getCalendarName();
  ```
- Then retrieve the *Calendar* from the Scheduler instance and check your timestamp:

  ```
  Calendar cal = sched.getCalendar(calendarName);
  boolean willFire = cal.includedisTimeIncluded(timeStampToCheck);
  ```